# Where does Microk8s keep kubelet.service?

Tags: kubelet, microk8s

I am trying to [enable a FlexVolume driver](https://github.com/Azure/kubernetes-volume-drivers/blob/master/flexvolume/README.md#config-kubelet-service-to-enable-flexvolume-driver) on Microk8s on Ubuntu.

To do that, it seems I have to edit the kubelet.service file. This is supposed to be stored in /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service but it is't present in my installation.

Where is it stored for Microk8s? Surely it has kubelet running somewhere?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `microk8s kubelet` service is present at the following location:

```
/etc/systemd/system/snap.microk8s.daemon-kubelet.service
```

You can always check that using the service daemon:

```
systemctl status snap.microk8s.daemon-kubelet
```

A little bit more information, to check what is running by microk8s, you can use:

```
velotio@velotio-ThinkPad-E470:~$ microk8s.inspect 
Inspecting services
  Service snap.microk8s.daemon-docker is running
  Service snap.microk8s.daemon-apiserver is running
  Service snap.microk8s.daemon-proxy is running
  Service snap.microk8s.daemon-kubelet is running
  Service snap.microk8s.daemon-scheduler is running
  Service snap.microk8s.daemon-controller-manager is running
  Service snap.microk8s.daemon-etcd is running
  Copy service arguments to the final report tarball
Inspecting AppArmor configuration
Gathering system info
  Copy network configuration to the final report tarball
  Copy processes list to the final report tarball
  Copy snap list to the final report tarball
  Inspect kubernetes cluster

 WARNING:  IPtables FORWARD policy is DROP. Consider enabling traffic forwarding with: sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT 
Building the report tarball
  Report tarball is at /var/snap/microk8s/354/inspection-report-20190112_162506.tar.gz
```